# How can I convert VectorSource to RasterSource

Tags: canvas, maps, gis, openlayers, openlayers-5

In OpenLayers `ol.source.ImageVector` has been deprecated since v5. 
[Docs](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.ImageVector.html) recommended to use an `ol.layer.Vector` with `renderMode: 'image'` instead. 
But what if I want to get an another raster **source** at output? (Not a layer)
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `ol.source.Raster` is always a raster source.  The input can be either a source or layer.

OpenLayers 4:

https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/KKpgrmx

```
new ol.source.Raster({
  sources: [
    new ol.source.ImageVector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector()
    })
  ]
})
```

OpenLayers 5:

```
new ol.source.Raster({
  sources: [
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector()
    }),
    renderMode: 'image'
  ]
})
```

OpenLayers 6:

https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/BaNLvyq

```
new ol.source.Raster({
  sources: [
    new ol.layer.VectorImage({
      source: new ol.source.Vector()
    })
  ]
})
```

Comment: But docs says, that sources of `ol.source.Raster` could be only objects that extend `ol.source.Source` object. `ol.layer.Vector` extends `ol.layer.Layer` object.

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't work. OpenLayers says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ol_lm' of null`

Comment: Which version are you using?  In versions 5 and 6 it can be subclasses of source or layer
https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_source_Raster-RasterSource.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Raster-RasterSource.html

Comment: I'm using v4.6.5

Comment: You can use `ol.source.ImageVector` in version 4 https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/KKpgrmx

Comment: It is deprecated

Comment: I posted a link to a working example using version 4.6.5.  It wasn't removed until version 5.